# Reverse sshfs tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, sshfs

Hey I want to setup a reverse sshfs tunnel. I have a home server which sits behind some type of NAT which makes it impossible for a remote computer to sshfs the home file system. On the local computer I run the following command to establish a reverse ssh tunnel:

`ssh -R 14443:localhost:22 remoteUser@remoteComp`

From the remote computer I can successfully ssh to the home server:

`ssh localUser@localhost -p 14443`

However I can not mount home file system:

`sshfs -p 14443 localUser@localhost:/home/localUser RemoteFolder/`

as I receive the following error:

`fuse: failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied`

Ofcourse the `remoteUser` has been added to the group `fuse`. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with the remote server I'm using. Fuse was not functioning on the Virtual Private Server(VPS), and the issue was resolved by the VPS admin. The admin had to 'enable fuse'.

This maybe an issue for VPS hosted with openvz.

Comment: Yeah this is why KVM is so much nicer to work with. You can enable kernel modules as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Could check on your remote system what the permission of /dev/fuse is? ls -l /dev/fuse.
It means that your user/group is not able to write to /dev/fuse on your remote system.

Comment: Heres the result `crw-rw---- 1 root fuse 10, 229 May  8 17:32 /dev/fuse` Do I need to change something? Thanks :).

Comment: So it is owned by group fuse. What does 'groups remoteUser' return? If you do not see fuse, then either you did not add it to the fuse group or need to log out and log in again.

Comment: In this case remoteUser = root. `groups root` returns `root : root fuse`. This is after logout & login, and sshfs is still returning the same error.